Class with the same name as namespace in TypeScript
When I do the following...
namespace Core.Error {
  export class ArgumentError extends Error {}
}

I get the error:

Type 'typeof Error' is not a constructor function type.ts(2507)

This is because Error can't be found.
If I do:
namespace Core.Blah {
  export class ArgumentError extends Error {}
}

Then Error can be found.
How can I make it so I can keep my namespace ending with the word Error, while extending the baked in Error class?
I've tried escaping Error like so \Error and a few other things, but nothing appears to work.
I want to use namespaces and not imports.

You're shadowing Error and then wanting to access it? You can probably use the globalThis namespace to write ArgumentError extends globalThis.Error, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

This is what I wanted, thanks.

Since the Error constructor is a global variable, you should be able to access it on the global object which should be available as globalThis (or window or global depending on your environment):
namespace Core.Error {
    export class ArgumentError extends globalThis.Error {  // okay

    }    
}

Or you could give it a name you haven't shadowed and grab that:
const MyError = Error;

namespace Core.Error {
    export class ArgumentError extends MyError { 

    }    
}

Of course it's probably not a great idea to shadow things you need to access.
Playground link to code
